# Installing package from source on an initial ram filesystem

Tags: linux, makefile, init

I'm trying to install multiple packages into an initial ram file system. I'm using uclibc as my C library. This could be a stupid question but...

Would the compiled program also need a C library installed onto the `initramfs`?

Am I right in thinking that when a program is compiled from source, it is compiled into some sort of executable? Will the application on the `initramfs` be ready to run once I have `make install`ed (with the correct prefix and providing dependencies are met )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a compiled program needs a C library - or any kind of library, for that matter - depends on how it was [linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29).

In general, if your program was linked [statically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) then it does not have any external dependencies - it only needs a working kernel. The executable code of any library that it depends on will have been incorporated into the final executable.

If, on the other hand, it is linked  [dynamically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_library), then it still needs the [shared object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_object#Shared_libraries) files of the libraries it depends on. On Linux, most library shared objects (also known as *shared libraries*) follow the convention of having a filename with either a `.so` extension or, in general, a `*.so.*` format. For example `/lib/libssl3.so` and `/lib/libncurses.so.5.9` are both shared libraries on my system.

It is also possible to have an executable that is statically linked against some libraries and dynamically linked against others. A common case where this happens is when rare or proprietary libraries are linked in statically, while standard system libraries are linked in dynamically.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Helped me a lot, Many thanks! One last question if you don't mind.. Are the Shared Object files machine independent? For example if my live distribution is identical in architecture to my host machine, can i just copy the shared object files across? Thanks again